# Автоклик при условии определенного разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытался сделать таким образом, но, к сожалению, это не верно.
Подскажите где я ошибся, а то немножко запутался

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var runWidth = $(window).width();

    if(runWidth < 440) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('list-view').click();
        }, 1000);

    } else if(winWidth < 660) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('grid-view').click();
        }, 1000);

    } else if(winWidth < 880) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('grid3-view').click();
        }, 1000);

    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('grid3-view').click();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы каждый раз проверять размер окна, лучше воспользоваться слушателем `onresize`

В качестве примера указал другие размеры для проверки.
В сниппете жмём "*На всю страницу*" и видим логи

```js
(window.onresize = function() {
  w = window.innerWidth;
  
  if(w < 900) { document.getElementById('list-view').click(); } else
  if(w < 1024) { document.getElementById('grid-view').click(); } else
  { document.getElementById('grid3-view').click(); }

})();
```

```html
<div id='list-view' onclick='console.log(innerHTML)'>list-view</div>
<div id='grid-view' onclick='console.log(innerHTML)'>grid-view</div>
<div id='grid3-view' onclick='console.log(innerHTML)'>grid3-view</div>
```

---

Если изменять размер окна курсором, при каждом сдвиге будет происходить клик. Чтобы это избежать, лучше задать область, при смене которой будут выполняться нужные действия.

Тоесть действия будут выполняться **только** в тот момент, когда диапазон области сменится

```js
(window.onresize = function() {
    w = window.innerWidth;

    area =
    w >= 1280 && w <= 1920 ? 2 :
    w >= 768 && w <= 1280 ? 1 : 0;
 
    if(typeof(range) == 'undefined' || range != area) {
        range = area;
  
        switch(range) {
            case 0: console.log('list-view', area, w); break
            case 1: console.log('grid-view', area, w); break
            case 2: console.log('grid3-view', area, w); break
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Кстати jquery здесь даже не нужен, это чистый js

Comment: jquery  [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) `$(window).resize(function() { ... });`